# Keep git repo files in sync across multiple development pc's

Tags: git, synchronization, development-environment, rsync

As I develop on multiple computers, I typically will check in/sync my curent work in progress to get it loaded on the second pc to allow further dev work.

I am curious if there is a specific tool that would allow my checked out files and edits to stay realtime or near realtime synced across my development pc's, since in effect it's like one person who is just wandering across multiple pc's.

I've considred using something like Resilio or rsync for this, but I will assume there are ways this can bite you. Thus why I'm curious if there is a more "official" way to accomplish this.

Comment: What if the different machines have different branches checked out? I solve your problem, and this one, with temp commits. I use a message like "WIP: some explanation" and then push it. But that won't work if you get pulled away from one computer so quickly that you don't have time to type the commit command, and then you don't return to that computer first. Not sure how often that happens to you...

Comment: right that is a common issue, but let's assume I just want whatever I'm currently working on to just be the same across my pc's. (and i don't have to remember to check in when I get up and walk out of the room ;)

Comment: I guess I'm not sure how you would do that unless the 3 computers were synced up on state too. If each computer has a different branch checked out, syncing your local files wouldn't make sense, because they each have a different starting point. How would you sync an edit to a file if that file doesn't even exist yet on another machine? It almost seems like you want to do all of your development on a single machine, and remote into it from the others.

Comment: I'm effectively trying to replicate the "remote into one machien" but by having the state always synced up.

Answer (score 0):

Well.... I guess that's what you would use git for.... anyway, given that you want to look kind of *outside* of git, I think you could take a look at gitfs:

https://github.com/presslabs/gitfs.

I would also recommend gitmod (full disclosure: my tool... well, one of many, apparently there are other gitmods out there), but it's not meant to keep stuff that's on a remote... *plus* it's read-only.

https://github.com/eantoranz/gitmod

Comment: whoa gitfs is wild